# ¿Como detectar cambios Sincronos? Angular 2+

Tags: http, angular5

Actualmente tengo dos aplicaciones una web y otra móvil, estas manejan un mismo backend. Como puedo detectar los cambios (Si existen) en ellas y actualizar dinamicamete las vistas?.

He buscado una implementación sencilla sin éxito.

Ejemplo: Si Actualizo un campo desde la plataforma web, que dicho cambio se me refleje en la plataforma móvil dinámicamente.

Estoy usando observables para hacer las consultas a los diferentes end-points.

```
  getAll(): Observable<T[]> {
    const getUrl = this.url + "/getAll";
    return this.http.get<T[]>(getUrl, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Comment: Tal como lo planteas, no podrás. Recuerda que cada aplicación es independiente. Por lo tanto, el método `subscribe` que usas para la aplicación web es diferente del método que usas en la aplicación móvil. Si deseas mantener actualizados los valores que se muestran en las vistas, independientemente de dónde se renderiza la misma (web o móvil) deberías usar algún sistema full dúplex, por ejemplo `sockets`. Saludos